# Using Vlookup with a part of a string (value)

Tags: vlookup

I'm trying to look for part of a value

my code is:

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A3,5),Inventory!A:F,6,FALSE)
```

A3 = 19017E (second code of a item)

I want to look for 19017 (main code) but get #N/A

Can some body help me?

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll take a stab at submitting a Stack Overflow answer. First time.

I believe it's returning #N/A because the LEFT() function returns a *text* value, whereas the value in the table of the VLOOKUP() function is a *number* value.

So, my suggestion is to convert it to a number with the VALUE() function within your VLOOKUP():

```
=VLOOKUP(VALUE(LEFT(A3,5)), Inventory!A:F,6,FALSE)
```

If some of your main codes also contain letters, that could be problematic.

That was my solution. Hope that helps.